# How to show 0.00 instead of 0

Tags: angular

```ts
export class AppComponent  {
  value1 = 0;
  value2 = 0.00;
  value3 = 0.01;
}
```

```html
<p>
  {{value1}} - shows 0
</p>
<p>
  {{value2}}  shows 0
</p>
<p>
  {{value3}}  shows 0.01
</p>
```

Hello, I need to show values in html with 2 places after decimal. For example I need to show 0.00 when it's 0. Is it possible?
Stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cm9yr

Comment: You are probably looking for the [decimal pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Comment: The number `0.00` is the same as `0`. Its string representation is `'0'`.

Answer (score 2):

Use .toFixed(decimals)

(0).toFixed(2); -> 0.00